# How to combine a numerical variable with a chrono literal?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Let's say I have a variable `int x = 2000` and I want to make a thread sleep for 'x milliseconds'. How do I combine the chrono literal `ms` with `x`?

I tried stuff like this:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for((x)ms);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(xms);
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with multithreading, right? You just want to make a time duration from an int.

Comment: std::chrono::milliseconds(x) is the way to go.

Comment: Oh, yeah that's right. I thought I entered thread.. Woops.

Comment: @DeiDei std::chrono::milliseconds(x) did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use a literal suffix with a variable. Only literals like `250ms` work.

Comment: `operator ""ms(x)` :-)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @DeiDei:

`std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x))` fixed my problem!